# Improve performance mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi all champions out there

I am far from a guru when it comes to high performance SQL queries and and wonder in anyone can help me improve the query below. It works but takes far too long, especially since I can have 100 or so entries in the IN () part.

The code is as follows, hope you can figure out the schema enough to help.

```
SELECT  inv.amount
FROM    invoice inv
WHERE   inv.invoiceID IN (
        SELECT  childInvoiceID
        FROM    invoiceRelation ir
                LEFT JOIN Payment pay ON pay.invoiceID = ir.parentInvoiceID
        WHERE   pay.paymentID IN ( 125886, 119293, 123497 ) )
```

Comment: Does your tables have indexes on the columns in the WHERE parts of your queries?

Comment: this is an inner join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restructure your query to use a join instead of a subselect. Also, use an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN to the Payment table. This is justified, since you have a WHERE filter that would filter rows without a match in the Payment table anyway.

```
SELECT inv.amount 
FROM invoice inv
INNER JOIN invoiceRelation ir ON inv.incoiceID = ir.childInvoiceID
INNER JOIN Payment pay on pay.invoiceID = ir.parentInvoiceID
WHERE pay.paymentID IN (...)
```

Comment: Wow what a difference. From 380 ms to 0.4 ms. Thanks also for you explanation to your solution, helps me understand. Thanks Dan.

Answer (score 2):

One way to improve performance is to have a good index on relevant columns. In your example, an index on `inv.invoiceI`D would probably speed up the query quite a bit.

Also on `pay.paymentID`

Try this and see if it helps:

```
ALTER TABLE invoice ADD INDEX invoiceID_idx (invoiceID);
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE Payment ADD INDEX paymendID_idx (paymentID);
```

Comment: +1  Most of the time, indexes are most important to improve performance of selects.

Comment: Yup I had the indexes there but I guess my query did not use them due to the huge where clause. Now they work :-) Thanks Jakob.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of first `in` you can use inner join.

```
select inv.amount from invoice inv 
inner join  invoiceRelation ir on (inv.invoiceID = ir.childInvoiceID)
LEFT JOIN Payment pay ON pay.invoiceID = ir.parentInvoiceID
WHERE pay.paymentID IN (125886,119293,123497)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try like this instead:

```
SELECT  inv.amount
FROM    invoice inv
inner join invoiceRelation ir on inv.invoiceID = ir.parentInvoiceID
left join Payment pay on pay.invoiceID = ir.parentInvoiceID 
WHERE  pay.paymentID IN ( 125886, 119293, 123497 )
```

(OR) better; if you sure you have a invoiceID FK in payment table then make that `left join` to a `inner join`.

In a nutshell, you should try avoiding correlated subquery at all times if you can replace that subquery to a join.

Comment: either way, it's an inner join